# Storing MultiSurface and PolygonPatches in SQL database - conversion to basic OGC geometry types

Tags: polygon, geometry, .net, surface, nettopologysuite

I am new to GIS.

I am working on a requirement of storing in the database administrative units (states, counties, communities, cities, etc.) as geometries (borders / areas) in order to be able to make queries based on contain operation
e.g. list units that contain given point (return community, country and state) or given polygon (return county that contains a city, both encoded only as polygons with no other relations defined

In the data I was given administrative units are defined using `MultiSufrace`, `SurfaceMembers`, `Surfaces`, `PolygonPatches`

As far as I was able to check SQL database providers and ORMs use only basic OGC defined geometries ( I know that PostGIS has some extended types but I would like to keep the solution compatible with multiple SQL providers)

The project is using the following tech stack

- .NET 5
- Net Topology Suite (NTS) 2.3
- Entity Framework Core 5.0.8
- Data storage layer needs to be compatible with SQL Server, SQLite and PostgreSQL

Under assumption all areas relate to administrative units, is it possible to convert GML geometries to geometries supported by EFCore / NTS / SQL Providers? According to EF Core documentation it supports only the following: `Geometry`, `Point`, `LineString`, `Polygon`, `GeometryCollection`, `MultiPoint`, `MultiLineString`, `MultiPolygon`. `CircularString`, `CompoundCurve`, and `CurvePolygon` are not supported by NTS.

Example of administrative unit GML geometry:

```
<gml:MultiSurface gml:id="..." srsName="urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::2180" srsDimension="2">
    <gml:surfaceMember>
        <gml:Surface gml:id="..." >
            <gml:patches>
                <gml:PolygonPatch>
                    <gml:exterior>
                        <gml:LinearRing>
                            <gml:posList>
                                ...
                            </gml:posList>
                        </gml:LinearRing>
                    </gml:exterior>
                    <gml:interior>
                        <gml:LinearRing>
                            <gml:posList>
                                ...
                            </gml:posList>
                        </gml:LinearRing>
                    </gml:interior>
                </gml:PolygonPatch>
            </gml:patches>
        </gml:Surface>
    </gml:surfaceMember>
</gml:MultiSurface>
```

Comment: GIS SE site policy of focused question allows only one question per question. Please edit your question and limit it to only one question.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at NTS GMLReader class. It has functionality to create a Geometry object from GML 2.1. Once you have a Geometry, you can use various NTS functions to convert it to the type that you want. Looking at your question I would guess Polygon or MultiPolygon would suit your needs, as they translate directly to OCG POLYGON and MULTIPOLYGON in the database.

Depending on what you plan to do with your database table later on it may be an idea to create all geometries as MultiPolygon. The database can mix Polygons and MultiPolygons in the same table, but if you're planning on using some map server to diplay maps, they usually are limited to one geometry type per layer. It also makes it easier to write the code as you don't have to check the actual type of a Geometry instance when performing NTS operations on them. It can also be an idea to make all geometries topologically correct before storing to database, as NTS will happily write them down, but when you try to do some Gis-operations on them it may fail if they are self-intersecting or otherwise invalid.

Comment: NTC current version and the GMLReader class does not support PolygonPatch only MultiPolygons. I am currently testing treating PolygonPatches as MultiPolygons - after all administrative units should not be described with overlapping areas.

Comment: NTS GMLReader class supports version 3 (in the limitted scope) , the namespace NetTopologySuite.IO.GML2 is a bit missleading https://github.com/NetTopologySuite/NetTopologySuite/pull/472

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that you had PolygonPatch and that those are not supported by NTS. You could of course take the long way and take out the relevant rings from the GML and then build your new Geometries by copying them to a MultiPolygon.